# Is there a size restriction on KML layer in esri map?

Tags: kml, layers, file-size

My web site utilizes ESRI's map and it contains several KML layers. Most of them show up fine except for the ones bigger than ~4MB. Are there any restrictions on KML file size?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I believe that KML layers are sent via http://utility.arcgis.com/sharing/kml in the background, which converts them into their component layers - this service may have a size limitation.

Comment: Which API are you using? JavaScript, Flex or Silverlight?

Comment: I'm using the javascript API.

Comment: @StephenLead how do I find out more about this service?

Comment: Hopefully one of the Esri team will see this - you could also try cross-posting to http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/15-ArcGIS-API-for-JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 4 MB should be a problem, because there is a size limitation but that is 10 MB. Please find more details in below link:
[Kml Limitations](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/kml.htm)